# In Swift, what is a DictionaryLiteralConvertible?

Tags: swift

If you place the following straightforward snippet of code into a Playground:

```
import Foundation

let humanReadableNames = [
    "test": NSLocalizedString("foo")
]
```

you'll get the compiler error:

```
Cannot confer the expression's type 'Dictionary' to type 'DictionaryLiteralConvertible'
```

The Swift function `NSLocalizedString` is defined to return a `String`, so I don't see why the type of this variable isn't simply `Dictionary<String, String>`.

Comment: your whole expression is a Dictionary, so I would guess it is how you use it later that causes the error... it seems that the parser has a lot of these little issues, like gcc used to.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to add the comment parameter to NSLocalizedString().

```
let humanReadableNames = [
            "test": NSLocalizedString("foo", comment:"bar")
        ]
```